# IntegrityError : yonetim_ders.ogretim_elemani_id may not be NUL

Tags: django

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class OgretimElemani(models.Model):
    adi = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    soyadi = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefonu = models.CharField(max_length = 10 , blank=True)
    e_posta_adresi = models.EmailField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.soyadi,self.adi)


class Ders(models.Model):
    kodu = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    adi = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ogretim_elamani = models.ForeignKey(OgretimElemani)
    tanimi = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.kodu,self.adi,self.ogretim_elamani)



class Ogrenci(models.Model):
    numarasi = models.IntegerField()
    adi = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    soyadi = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    aldigi_dersler = models.ManyToManyField(Ders)

    def __unicode__(self):  
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.soyadi,self.adi,self.aldigi_dersler)
```

Django shell :

```
>>>ders1=Ders(kodu='KIM101', adi='Kimya-1')
>>>ders1.ogretim_elemani=OgretimElemani[0]
>>>ders1.save()

IntegrityError : yonetim_ders.ogretim_elemani_id may not be NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You must assign a `OgretimElemani` instance that has already been saved to the database.

For example, the following should work.

```
>>> ders1 = Ders(kodu='KIM101', adi='Kimya-1'
>>> ogretim_elemani = OgretimElemani.objects.all()[0] # fetch the first one from the database
>>> ders1.ogretim_elemani = ogretim_elemani
>>>ders1.save()
```

Your example is not very clear because you use `OgretimElemani[0]`. You shouldn't reuse the variable name `OgretimElemani`, it makes the code confusing.

Comment: Thank you for answering but I've found the solution ... I made a migration 'yonetim(which is my app name)' and it worked :)